# Other than out of sample error, are there any other ways of comparing goodness of fit of two models, when the models come from different families?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, model, in-sample

I'm asking this within the context of time series, but the question would apply to any regression type learning problem.

It usually specified that using information criteria like the AIC or the BIC to compare different models works only if the models come from the same family of models (e.g all the models are ARIMA models of with different orders, or the models are all regressions with different numbers of regressors, etc...).

But what if I want to compare the performance of an ARIMA model and an Exponential Smoothing model and *I don't want to (or can't) use out of sample error*?

What options do I have, since the AIC or the BIC are no longer valid comparison criteria?

Comment: you mentioned goodness of fit in the title but then didn't reference goodness of fit in your question. Are you disregarding `R^2` (and its many cousins) intentionally?

Comment: @ChrisUmphlett my understanding is that maximizing $R^2$ amounts to the same thing as minimizing $SSE$, which is a simplistic criterion since it can easily lead to overfitting.

Comment: `R^2` can only increase as one adds parameters, so yes maximizing it can lead one to overfit. If you're just comparing models then you may not have that risk though (rather than using it to evaluate and change a single model). But I referenced its "cousins" because there are other versions that are improved. `Adjusted R^2` for instance can decrease if irrelevant parameters are added. [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination)